# javascript caesar cipher algorithm

Tags: javascript, regex, string, encryption

Is there anyway to do this function?, because i find it quite difficult to understand, specially that function with a char parammeter which i dont see where or how i use it.

```
function trans(msg, rot) {
    //Reemplaza cada letra encontrada de la expresion [a-z], por el caracter codificado de la funcion
    return msg.replace(/([a-z])/ig,
        function(char) {
            var codASCII = char.charCodeAt(0);
            return String.fromCharCode( codASCII >= 97 ? (codASCII + rot + 26 - 97) % 26 + 97 : (codASCII + rot + 26 - 65) % 26 + 65 );
        });
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: What is your question? I'll guess you should figure that out when you search for 'ceasar cipher' and 'ascii table'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us have a look at [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)'s function definition:

```
str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function [, flags]);
```

In JavaScript, we can pass a replacement function to the `String.replace` function. How the arguments of the function is populated is described [in this section of MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Basically:

- The first argument is the string that matches the whole expression (equivalent to `$&` in replacement string)
- Followed by the content of the capturing groups (equivalent to `$n` where `n` is positive number). There will be as many arguments as the number of capturing groups.
- Followed by offset of the main match
- And the last argument is the input string.

So whatever matched by `/([a-z])/ig` will be supplied to the replacement function as the first argument (`char` in this case). The character matched will be processed and returned as the replacement.

In your code, `/([a-z])/ig` can be simplified to `/[a-z]/ig`, since the replacement function only refers to the main match.

Comment: Thank you very much, i find very clear your answere.