# javascript regex skip square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
var oldName = "questions[0].answers[3].answer";
```

I want to increment the the answers part to [4]( +1 of what the current value is).
If it is `questions[0].answers[6].answer` it should become questions[0].answers[7].answer.

I tried with the following but I am not getting any result.

```
var matches = oldName.match(/(\d+)answers(\d+)/)
var number1 = Number(matches[1]);
var number2 = Number(matches[2]);
```

I need to store the numbers in the string in 2 separate variables.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because I am cloning an element using jQuery and after the clone I need to increment the name or the id of the element and make the element unique in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple to do this, just supply a replacement function to [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
str.replace(/answers\[(\d+)\]/, function (_, $1) {
     return "answers[" + (+$1 + 1) + "]";
});
```

(If you want an explanation on the parameters to the replacement function, you can read the MDN link above, or [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584958/javascript-caesar-cipher-algorithm/26585752#26585752))

But whether this is a good solution to the bigger problem, I don't know.

Comment: `var oldname = oldname.replace...` is bad code, and I don't think it is necessary to make more changes to the code.